# how to covert a vector of integers with no repeats to multiple consecutive and discrete parts, and export in a specific format using R?

Tags: r

Below is a sample data:

```
dat<-c(1:10,14,17:20,30)
```

My desired output format is:

```
1-10,14,17-10,30
```

I have a large similar vector, that's why I try to use R to make it. Can anyone give some hints\suggestions? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `diff` to create groups of consecutive values and use it in `tapply` where you can paste first and last value of each group if the length of the values is greater than 1.

```
dat <- c(1:10,14,17:20,30)

result <- as.character(tapply(dat, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(dat) > 1)), function(x) {
  if(length(x) == 1) x else paste(x[1], x[length(x)], sep = '-')
}))

result
#[1] "1-10"  "14"    "17-20" "30"
```

If you want output as one string.

```
toString(result)
#[1] "1-10, 14, 17-20, 30"
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution (very similar in principle to Ronak's:

```
sapply(split(dat, cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(dat) > 1))), function(x){
    paste(unique(range(x)), collapse = "-")
  }
)
```